# "Ago" date/time functions in Ruby/Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime

I was wondering if there's a way in Rails to calculate time stamp like - half a minute ago, 2 minute ago, 1 day ago etc. Something like twitter real time date stamp.

I want to know if Ruby/Rails has a built-in function for such date-time conversion?

Answer (score 211, accepted):

You can use:

```
10.minutes.ago
2.days.since
```

Or in your views you have the helpers:

```
distance_of_time_in_words(from_time, to_time)
time_ago_in_words(from_time)
```

Check [the API](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html#M002261) for details and more options.

Comment: As of Rails 3 its now `10.minutes.ago` instead of mins.

Comment: If you're outside of Rails, `require 'active_support'` (at least if Rails 2.X is installed).

Comment: require 'active_support/all' or if using bundle: gem "activesupport", :require => "active_support"

Comment: Did anyone else naturally try `1.day.ahead` and was disappointed that didn't work.

Comment: @stevec you can do that with `1.day.from_now`

Answer (score 15):

You can use available methods to get the time in past or future using [`ago`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.2/classes/Time.html#method-i-ago), [`since`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.2/classes/Time.html#method-i-since) alias for `from_now` and many available methods

```
Time.current
#=> Tue, 20 Sep 2016 15:03:30 UTC +00:00

2.minutes.ago
#=> Tue, 20 Sep 2016 15:01:30 UTC +00:00

2.minutes.since
#=> Tue, 20 Sep 2016 15:05:30 UTC +00:00 

1.month.ago
#=> Sat, 20 Aug 2016 15:03:30 UTC +00:00

1.year.since
#=> Wed, 20 Sep 2017 15:03:30 UTC +00:00
```

Check all the available methods in [Time](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.2/classes/Time.html) class

Answer (score 5):

[distance_of_time_in_words](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html#method-i-distance_of_time_in_words):

```
from_time = Time.now

distance_of_time_in_words(from_time, from_time + 50.minutes) # => about 1 hour
distance_of_time_in_words(from_time, 50.minutes.from_now) # => about 1 hour
distance_of_time_in_words(from_time, from_time + 15.seconds) # => less than a minute
distance_of_time_in_words(from_time, from_time + 15.seconds, include_seconds: true) # => less than 20 seconds
```

[time_ago_in_words](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html#method-i-time_ago_in_words):

```
time_ago_in_words(3.minutes.from_now) # => 3 minutes
time_ago_in_words(3.minutes.ago) # => 3 minutes
time_ago_in_words(Time.now - 15.hours) # => about 15 hours
```