# Display datetime like 1 hour ago, 5 hours ago, 3 days ago, 

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you do relative time in Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/195740/how-do-you-do-relative-time-in-rails)

I want to display the datetime like this:

```
30 seconds ago
1 hour ago
9 hours ago
2 days ago
1 year ago
..
```

Is this built in or should I write my own function to do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you do relative time in Rails?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/195740/how-do-you-do-relative-time-in-rails) or [How do you say something happened “x minutes ago” or “x hours ago” or “x days ago” in Ruby?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1570752/how-do-you-say-something-happened-x-minutes-ago-or-x-hours-ago-or-x-days-ago) or [“Ago” date/time functions in Ruby/Rails](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3278986/ago-date-time-functions-in-ruby-rails)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html#method-i-distance_of_time_in_words